# How to make esp32 wake-up signal and standby signal using android app via BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am working on an android application where it should send a signal to esp32 to "wake it up" and make it "standby mode".

Comment: If standby mode means deep sleep you are out of luck. Deep sleep can only be exited using a timer or a gpio pin on the device, not BLE. If an immediate wake up is not required you could wake up the esp32 every x seconds to listen to BLE advertisements of your phone. If found stay awake, if not found go back to sleep

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I see, Okk understood